# Regex Pattern for not allowing slash on beginning and ending and not allowing special characters except slash, underscore, space

Tags: regex

I have a requirement with this list

1. No slash(/), underscore(_), and spaces( ) at the beginning and ending.
2. Alphanumeric with spaces, underscore, slash in between of string are allowed.
3. All special characters are not allowed except slash(/), underscore(_), and spaces( ).

test  - (incorrect) space at the end
test - (correct) no space at the end
 test - (incorrect) space at the beginning
54test/ - (incorrect) / at the end
/54test - (incorrect) / at the beginning
54test/one - (correct)
54test one/my - (correct)
54test /my - (incorrect)

Here's my current regex but I can't really expand it because I'm pretty new with regex. and I Just get this at some post in SO

```
^[a-z0-9](?!.*?[^\na-z0-9]{2}).*?[a-z0-9]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[_\/ ][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H9SlGu/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%2B(%3F%3A%5B_%2F%20%5D%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%2B)*%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`  - 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `(?:[_\/ ][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - 0 or more repetitions of `_`, `/` or space and then 1+ alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string