# Python regex only matching a single "/" after alphanumeric characters

Tags: python, regex, alphanumeric

I am keeping track of resources with index paths like, `A/B/C`. I want to validate user input using regular expression in Python.

- Must start with an alphanumeric character
- Must end with an alphanumeric character
- Only one forward-slash is used to separate component.
- Empty string is not valid
- A single component is valid (e.g. `A`)

I have this so far,

```py
^(?!/)(?:[0-9a-zA-Z/]+)(?<!/)$
```

It passes correctly `A/B/C` but also passes `A//B///C`! I want to enforce with the regular expression that only one forward-slash can be used to separate components.

Here is a working example, https://regex101.com/r/MBblVG/1

[image: Screenshot from regular expression website]

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$`?

Comment: If you are adding `uri` tag to your question then you had to know that `http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Alan%22Dutch%22Schaefer` is a **valid** URI ... with 2 slashes

Comment: is `abc` valid?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I removed that tag as these are not URI, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for. Please make an answer so I can mark as closed. The other question was not python based. This may be useful even though a duplicate.

Comment: You can't imagine how many such questions already exist. I have [just answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57586668/3832970) an almost identical question. If reopened I will post.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OK I understand, thanks again.